# Unable to download pdf file through jQuery, Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got a vb.net handler file which send the pdf like this :

```
context.Response.Clear()
context.Response.StatusCode = 200
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf; charset=utf-8"
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & filename)
context.Response.Write(pdfContent)
context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

I tried something like this on the javascript side :

```
$ajax(url, {
type: "POST",
dataType: "text",
data: JSON.stringify(idRequestObj),
contentType: "application/pdf; charset=utf-8",
contentDisposition: "attachment; filename=print.pdf",
success: function (pdfContent) {
    if (pdfContent != null && pdfContent != "") {
        var blob = new Blob([pdfContent], { type: 'application/pdf; charset=utf-8' });
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = "file.pdf";
        link.click();
     }
     else{
         //smthg
     },
error://error handled
};
```

For now, it download a pdf but it is blank.

I do not have access to download.js.
I must use a "post" type request.
Any idea why my pdf is blank ?
I must use ajax.

p.s: it must work for IE 10 at least.

Comment: your ajax is riddled with typos .. `$ajax` -> `$.ajax` and it should be `$.ajax({url: url etc})`

Comment: Hi, my bad for the $.ajax, I make a mistake when writting it in the post. About the url syntax, both syntax (mine and yours) work. The problem is somewhere else. I guess this is an encoding error between the way the back-end send the pdf and the way the javascript get it. But I still don't get the problem...

Comment: some post like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49140246/how-to-send-pdf-file-to-frontend proposes to change the datatype by 'binary' or 'arraybuffer'. When I tried to change datatype from one of them, it raises an error : 'Sorry there are some errors, please try later.'